# Wrong order in for-loop in node.js (google calendar api, mongojs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-calendar-api, mongojs

I'm having a problem with a for loop in node.js. I'm listing all the events in google calendar and checking if they have been added to my mongo database. The for-loop goes through each event (here I am not yet inserting it into the db, only testing):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        console.log("first");
        console.log(event);
        db.events.find({googId = event.id}, function(err, doc) {
            if (doc.length == 0) {
                console.log("second");
                console.log(event);
            }
    }
```

So when I check the console, it first has all the "firsts" printed in order, after which it has "second" and only the last event in the list in every iteration. I'm a bit confused, as I expected it to show e.g. (assuming event1 and event2 have not yet been added to the mongo database):

```
first
event1
second
event1
first
event2
second
event2
```

instead of:

```
first
event1
first
event2
second
event2
second
event2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this not simply the case of the loop finishing before the callbacks get executed?

Comment: Thanks! I'm still pretty new to JS, so I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: Yes the asynchronous nature does take a little getting used to to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment for your question is absolutely correct, db.events.find() operation is asynchronous (it has a callback) and your for loop is synchronous and get executed before the asynchronous database query operations finished.